# Cant access a button which is positioned in a listView in code behind?

Tags: asp.net, listview

Can someone tell me why i cant access a button which is positioned in a listView in code behind?

here is my list

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>                        
                    <asp:Button ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' OnClick="LinkButton3_Click"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>            

    </asp:ListView>
```

and i cant do this on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(LinkButton3);
}
```

linkButton3 does not exist in current context. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(ListView1.FindControl("LinkButton3")); I tried using this. But it dosent seem to work

Comment: Is there an update panel somewhere that you are trying trigger an partial post back with the LinkButton3 click event? Could you show a bit more code and explain what your trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

From the code you provided.

The Button is in the ItemTemplate. You can add an ItemDataBound event handler to the ListView. Then in that event you will be able to access the Button.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td>                        
                <asp:Button ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' OnClick="LinkButton3_Click"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>            
</asp:ListView>
```

Then in code behind

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem)e.Item;

    //if this item is not being edited, find controls declared in ItemTemplate
    if (ListView1.EditItem == null || (ListView1.EditItem != null && dataItem.DisplayIndex != ListView1.EditIndex))
    {
        Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton3");
    }

    //if this item is being edited, find controls declared in the EditItemTemplate
    if (ListView1.EditItem != null && dataItem.DisplayIndex == ListView1.EditIndex)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)ListView1.EditItem.FindControl("LinkButton3");
    }
}
```

Comment: So whats actually item data bound property doing?

Comment: Well in my example its not doing anything except showing you how to use FindControl to get the button. The answer your initial question is, the reason you cannot access the button in PageLoad is because it is declared in the ItemTemplate of a templated Control. You can access it in ItemDataBound event.